# Firebase NextJS Deploy error copying files

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am using `Firebase` to deploy my `NextJS` app to `Firebase Hosting`. I get an error that seems to be related to copying a non-existent file from the `.next` folder to the `.firebase` folder. This is the error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\...\.next\server\pages\index.html' -> 'C:\Users\...\.firebase\...\hosting\index.html'`

The `index.html` file appears to be in `.next/app` folder.

I have the latest `firebase-tools` and am running `@next:13.4.19` and `react@18.2.0` with `firebase-tools@12.6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I hadn't installed the latest `firebase-tools` CLI globally!
I installed the latest `12.6.1` and it worked ... sort of ...
I now have a completely separate issue which is that all of my static images are not loading `404`.